# Simplest way to prevent iTunes from automatically launching when iPhone/iPad is connected

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes, ipad

When I connect my iPad or iPhone to my Mac iTunes automatically launches. What is the simplest way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The simplest way is to un-tick the `Automatically sync this...` box* on the Summary Screen for the device in iTunes when the device is connected:

[image: Open iTunes Tick Box]

- This is per device.

Alternatively you can just remove the iTunesHelper service under your Login Items which will disable it irrelevant of the tick box state.

Comment: This option seems to have changed in iTunes 11.2. There's now "Automatically sync when this iPad is connected" (or 'iPhone'). Disabling that option prevents auto-sync even when iTunes is manually opened, so the login item removal seems the most appropriate if you wish to retain that functionality.

Comment: This option doesn't exists anymore with the latest *iTunes* version. See @kreker answer more up to date.

Answer (score 22):

From the iTunes menu at the top go to **iTunes>Preferences>Devices>Prevent iPods, iPhones and iPads from syncing automatically**. Check the box at the bottom of that window. Click OK, quit iTunes.

That will stop iTunes from launching when you connect the phone stop automatic syncing.

Comment: This plus the other answers seem to end the problem if you're in 2015.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Apple's iTunes on Windows 8 or Windows 10, you can disable iTunesHelper by executing the following instructions:

1. Right click the task bar
2. Select the Task Manager

   [image]
3. Click the Startup tab
4. Click the iTunesHelper app
5. Click the Disable button
6. Close the Task Manager

   [image]

You can also right-click the iTunesHelper app and select Disable from the context menu.

Comment: The question says "When I connect my iPad or iPhone to my Mac", so a Windows-specific answer is unhelpful.

Comment: @pndc, true. Please feel free to downvote. I'm guessing it got upvotes because Windows users searched for this problem, ended up here, and it worked for them. I've found myself on Mac forums that helped me with Windows problems like this AND on Windows forums that helped me solve a Mac problem. But technically, yes, this solution does not belong here.

Answer (score 5):

For all those who **never** use iTunes and do not have that 'Summary' panel (not sure why this happens, perhaps iTunes version too old)

I just disabled execution for iTunes altogether.

So, open terminal and `sudo chmod -x /Applications/iTunes.app/` - never see iTunes again.

Comment: this won't work on recent macOS versions due to SIP.

Answer (score 4):

iTunes Helper is no longer shown as a login item, so the technique of removing this to keep iTunes away no longer works. However, there is an `ignore-devices` configuration value to tell the helper to stop launching iTunes when a device is attached.

Set this option like so (seems to take effect immediately):

```
defaults write com.apple.iTunesHelper ignore-devices 1
```

This allows you to keep auto sync enabled in iTunes (so it will sync when you decide to launch it manually), while also keeping iTunes from still popping up when your device has a software update available.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the option mentioned in the other answers is no longer present on iTunes. Instead, the OSX solution is now similar to the Windows one:

1. Open **System Preferences**
2. Select **Users & Groups**
3. Select your user profile if not selected already
4. Go into the **Login items** tab
5. Select and remove **iTunes Helper** from the list
6. Log out and back in, or restart OSX

Comment: This isn't available on Mojave (first mac since Leopard so not sure if it disappeared sooner).

Answer (score 1):

If you NEVER use iTunes and simply want to charge your devices without seeing the annoying pop-up every time, you can simply **rename the iTunes app**.

#### Solution for Mac:

1. Make sure your iTunes app is off.
2. Open Terminal and enter:

   > `cd /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS && sudo mv iTunes iTunes_off`
3. Enter your admin password and you should be all set.

#### UNDO

If you need to UNDO this later, all you need to do is **rename it back**, i.e.:

> `cd /Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS && sudo mv iTunes_off iTunes`

P.S. This is a similar to @YemSalat solution from Jun 1 '16 (+1), except for this one is a bit more obvious if you come back 6 months later.

P.P.S. If you update iTunes it may restore the original functionality.

Comment: "Operation not permitted"

Answer (score 0):

- Connect the iPhone/iPad/iPod device to the computer
- Inside iTunes, click on the device and then click on the ‘Summary’ tab
- Scroll to the bottom of the Summary tab selections until you see “Options”
- Click on the checkbox next to ‘Open iTunes when this iPhone is connected’ – wording will be slightly different if your device is an iPad or iPod or whatever
- Close iTunes

Answer (score 0):

Here is one additional hint to prevent any system app from launch on iPhone/iPad/Camera connection:

1. Launch app "Image Capture" by typing its name in Spotlight by `Ctrl+Space`

[image: Image Capture app screenshot]

2. In bottom left corner use combo box to select "No application"

[image: Combo box screenshot]