# How to stop apps from opening automatically when I plug things in

Tags: ios, itunes, photos.app, macos

I do iOS development work, and I can't stand how iTunes and iPhoto automatically open when I plug in a device.

I don't want anything to ever open automatically when I plug something in.

How do I make it so?

Comment: also possible duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/27318

Answer (score 3):

In iPhoto > Preferences > General select "Connecting Camera opens: no application"

In iTunes select your device and go to Summary and make sure "Automatically sync when this iPhone [or whatever device it is] is connected" is unchecked.

*I'm not certain the second one will completely solve opening iTunes since I can't test it as I don't have a cable here with me.*

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that iTunes no longer opens upon iPhone connect when you un-check the "Automatically sync when this iPhone is connected" option under the "Summary" tab when in your iPhone settings in iTunes (see below) :)

[image: iTunes auto sync feature]